# How to say some Greetings in germany

Tags: sentence-structure

Some Greetings sentenses in English can you tell me how german native speakers use in Alltag!

- i have no news of him(like Ali)
- He's not back home yet. There's no sign of him
- Whats up?
- How's it going with Ali?/How's everything with Ali?
- How’s the new job goning?
- Ok,leave it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ich habe nichts von Ali gehört
- Er ist noch nicht nach Hause gekommen. Er hat kein Lebenszeichen von sich gegeben
- Wie geht´s ? / Was geht ab ? / Was gibt´s ?
- Wie geht es Ali ?
- Wie läuft es im neuen Job ?
- Ok, ich kümmere mich darum.

Comment: Thank you so much but as moderator said , my question is off topic so i deleted